# What is the correct way to format a hasMany/through relationship using Bookshelfjs?

Tags: javascript, orm, join, bookshelf.js

I am having trouble crafting a `hasMany/through` relationship using Bookshelf.js. Here are the specific tables I am working with:

[image]

A term can have many translations and each translation references a term.

`term.id` -> `translation.source`

`translation.target` -> `term.id`

I am trying to craft a query that will take a term and return all related terms through a translation.

This is what I have in my Term class:

```
export const Term = Model.extend({
  tableName: 'terms',

  //... other methods

  englishTranslations() {
    return this.hasMany('Term', 'id').through('Translation', 'id', 'source', 'id', 'target');
  }
});
```

I run into an exception within the [select method within sync.js](https://github.com/tgriesser/bookshelf/blob/master/src/sync.js#L137) where `relatedData.pivotColumns` is `undefined` causing `through.parse` to throw.

I am confused about how to reference foreign keys correctly when constructing the `through` call and would appreciate any help anyone could provide.